# Possible combinations of column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is like this

```
Col1  Col2 Col3
10     7    1
11     8    0
12     7    0
12     4    1
11     2    1
10     7    1
```

I want the output like

```
Col1  Col2  Col3 Count
10     7     1     2
11     8     0     1
12     7     0     1
12     4     1     1
11     2     1     1
10     7     1     2
```

Comment: what `Count` column is representing?

Answer (score 1):

`transform` is what you need:

```
# A dummy column for now so that `groupby` has something to `count` on
df['count'] = 0

# The actual count
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']).transform('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this, assuming your data frame is not indexed (explanation on comments):

```
df2 = (df.reset_index() # we want to keep the order
         .merge(df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
                  .size() # count the occurrences
                  .to_frame('Count'), # give name to new column
                on=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
         .sort_values(by='index') # keep original order
         .drop(columns='index')) # remove the index we used to order
```